# How to Modify consecutive gfi-windows over HTML DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, frontend

I am modifying the values of gfi (getFeatureInfo) window using the DOM. The situation is following, at a crossing the two consecutive gfi-windows appear:

[Picture of gfi-Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtlNU.png)

[Picture of Html Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkzLy.png)

The gfi is modified using the code below. But the modification changes the values on current gfi-window and then they are fixed globally and passed on to the next gfi-window as well. The goal is to insert the respective description of "Canaltype" & "Material" on everytime new gfi-window appears using javascript-DOM code. What could be the best possible solution for this problem via front end/ DOM? Thank you.

```
Table_1 = document.getElementsByClassName("table table-hover");
for (var i = 0; i < Table_1[0].firstElementChild.childNodes.length; i++) {
    if (Table_1[0].firstElementChild.childNodes[i].getElementsByClassName("bold firstCol")[0].innerText == 'Canaltype') {
          // store the values from the row 
          Rows_1 = Table_1[0].firstElementChild.childNodes[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
          // Insert the canaltyp code to the respective attribute
          if (Rows_1[1].innerText == '5') { Rows_1[1].innerText = 'Free-flow line';}
   } else if (Table_1[0].firstElementChild.childNodes[i].getElementsByClassName("bold firstCol")[0].innerText == 'Material') {
         // store the values from the row 
        Rows_1 = Table_1[0].firstElementChild.childNodes[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
       // Insert the Material code to the respective attribute
       if (Rows_1[1].innerText == '29') { Rows_1[1].innerText = 'Vitrified clay';}
  }
}
```

Result from my DOM code with errors:
[Picture of First gfi is correct and the modification passing over to next gfi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsyPq.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551); provide a proper [mre] of the issue instead.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for your suggestion. But it was not possible to put all the code. I will try to create an example for easyness/feasibility.